# Multiple Y-axis on graph not aligned

Tags: r, d3.js, plotly

[image]

I created a graph through R's Plotly library.
The graph has 2 y-axis's and everything looks fine, except that the y-axis's are misaligned. 
How do I "realign" it?

Comment: Please make this a reproducible example by providing sample data and code.

Answer (score 3):

Python answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101767/python-plotly-align-y-axis-for-scatter-and-bar)

Had the same issue, add `rangemode = "tozero"` to your overlaying axis

```
plot_ly(data = dat,
      x = x,
      y = y,
      type = "bar",
      name = "Y") %>%
add_trace(data = par,
          x = x,
          y = Z,
          name = "Z",
          yaxis = "y2") %>%
layout(yaxis2 = list(overlaying = "y",
                     side = "right",
                     rangemode = "tozero"))
```

Comment: You made my day. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

In the `layout` function, you can set axis ranges manually.  You can use this to align them.  Often, the scale of your two traces will be very different, though.

```
plot_ly(...) %>%
add_trace(..., yaxis = "y2") %>%
layout(
  yaxis = list(
    range = c(-2, 2)
  ),
  yaxis2 = list(
    range = c(-2, 2)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually align primary and secondary y axes at any value (not just at 0) and for any plotting function by calculating new y axis limits. Here's a link to some code for a function that can handle any scenario: https://github.com/davidblakneymoore/A-Function-for-Aligning-Values-Across-Multiple-Vertical-Axes-in-Plots-in-R.

Comment: Is this function compatible with `plotly` or `ggplot2`? It looks like all of the examples use base R for plotting.

Comment: The examples I used only used `base` R functions for plotting, but those examples used output that the function had already produced. The function itself just returns axis limits and those limits can be plugged into any graphing function from any package

Answer (score 0):

This answer in python took JohnCoene's answer one step further:
https://community.plotly.com/t/align-multiple-y-axis-to-one-value-in-plotly/44500/2

The parameters `scaleratio` can be seen in further detail in the [Plotly manual](https://plotly.com/r/axes/).

By constraining the left and right y-axes to one another you can adjust the scale at which they increase.

```r
plot_ly(data = dat,
      x = x,
      y = y,
      type = "bar",
      name = "Y") %>%
add_trace(data = par,
          x = x,
          y = Z,
          name = "Z",
          yaxis = "y2") %>%
layout(yaxis = list(scaleanchor = 'y2',
                    scaleratio = 1, # Or perhaps 0.5 or 2, dep on your figure
                    constraintoward = 'bottom',
                    rangemode = "tozero"),
       yaxis2 = list(scaleanchor = 'y',
                     scaleratio = 1, # Or perhaps 0.5 or 2, dep on your figure
                     overlaying = "y",
                     constraintoward = 'bottom'
                     side = "right",
                     rangemode = "tozero"))
```