# Plotly Python: Align X-Axes in a grouped bar chart with multiple Y-axis

Tags: python, bar-chart, plotly

I have a grouped bar chart with two y axis each of them on a different scale. I am trying to align x-axis(y=0) of both the groups. I found few links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101767/python-plotly-align-y-axis-for-scatter-and-bar) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880139/multiple-y-axis-on-graph-not-aligned?noredirect=1&lq=1) in which setting **rangemode='zero'** should work, however my data consists of negative values due to which I guess setting rangemode to zero isn't working.

Here is my code:

```
import plotly.offline as plt
import plotly.graph_objs as go
traces = [go.Bar(x=[1,2,3,4], y=[-1,2,-3,4], name='y actual'), 
          go.Bar(x=[1], y=[0], name='y dummy', hoverinfo='none', showlegend=False), 
          go.Bar(x=[1],y=[0],yaxis='y2', name='y2 dummy', hoverinfo='none', showlegend=False),
          go.Bar(x=[1,2,3,4], y=[22, 2, 13, 25], yaxis='y2', name='y2 actual')]
layout = go.Layout(barmode='group',
                   yaxis=dict(title='y actual', rangemode="tozero", anchor='x', overlaying='y2'),
                   yaxis2=dict(title='y2 actual', side='right', rangemode = "tozero", anchor='x'))
fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
plt.iplot(fig)
```

The plot generated by the above code:
[image]

How do I fix this?

Note: You can see two dummy traces in the code. I introduced them so that the two traces 'y actual' and 'y2 actual' don't overlay over one another. For more info on why I did that checkout this [link](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/78#issuecomment-175301348)

Answer (score 4):

A possible workaround:

set the `range` element for both graphs to be proportional to each other then the axes will line up. Basically, your problem is one axis has to show negative numbers and the other doesn't. By telling `y2` to show negative numbers we obtain our goal.

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

traces = [
    go.Bar(
        x=[1, 2, 3, 4], 
        y=[-1, 2, -3, 4], 
        name='y actual'
    ), 
    go.Bar(
        x=[1], 
        y=[0], 
        name='y dummy', 
        hoverinfo='none', 
        showlegend=False
    ), 
    go.Bar(
        x=[1],
        y=[0],
        yaxis='y2', 
        name='y2 dummy', 
        hoverinfo='none', 
        showlegend=False
    ),
   go.Bar(
       x=[1, 2, 3, 4], 
       y=[22, 2, 13, 25], 
       yaxis='y2', 
       name='y2 actual'
   )
]

# layout
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='group',
    yaxis=dict(
        title='y actual', 
        rangemode="tozero", 
        #anchor='x', 
        overlaying='y2',
        side="left",
        range = [-4, 10]
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        title='y2 actual', 
        side='right', 
        rangemode = "tozero",
        #anchor='x',
        range = [-12, 30]
    )
)

# make fig
fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

[image]

This may be annoying to have to keep them in proportion but it will ensure their alignment.

to help automate the process you can use the following function to produce two ranges that are proportional to each other.

```
def make_proportional_intervals(a, b):
    """
    Given two list like objects, compute two proprotionally sized ranges.
    This function assumes the max value in both lists is positive and non-zero
    """
    min_a, min_b = min(a), min(b)
    max_a, max_b = max(a), max(b)
    if (min_a >=0) & (min_b >= 0):
        # provide a 20% cushion to the scale
        return [0, round(1.2*max_a)], [0, round(1.2*max_b)]
    else:
        if (min_a < min_b) & (max_a < max_b):
            n = -(-max_b // max_a)
            # n = math.ceil(max_b / max_a), if you cannot assume ints.
            return [min_a, max_a], [n*min_a, n*max_a]

        elif (min_b < min_a) & (max_b < max_a):
            n = -(-max_a // max_b)
            # n = math.ceil(max_b / max_a), if you cannot assume ints.
            return [n*min_b, n*max_b], [min_b, max_b]

        elif (min_b < min_a) & (max_a < max_b):
            n = max( -(-max_b // max_a), -(min_b // min_a) )
            return [min_b / n, max_b / n], [min_b, max_b]

        elif (min_a < min_b) & (max_b < max_a):
            n = max( -(-max_a // max_b), -(min_a // min_b) )
            return [min_a, max_a], [min_a / n, max_a / n]
        elif (min_a == min_b):
            m = max(max_a, max_b)
            return [min_a, m], [min_b,  m]
        elif max_a == max_b:
            m = min(min_a, min_b)
            return [m, max_a], [m, max_b]
```

This function assumes your values will be integers but if not you can `import math` and use `math.ceil()` instead of my integer division. I was avoiding adding any more imports. If you want to see this code in action I created an example in jupyter notebook that you can run multiple times to see how it handles different arrays.

```
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

def make_proportional_intervals(a, b):
    """
    Given two list like objects, compute two proprotionally sized ranges.
    This function assumes the max value in both lists is positive and non-zero
    """
    min_a, min_b = min(a), min(b)
    max_a, max_b = max(a), max(b)
    if (min_a >=0) & (min_b >= 0):
        # provide a 20% cushion to the scale
        return [0, round(1.2*max_a)], [0, round(1.2*max_b)]
    else:
        if (min_a < min_b) & (max_a < max_b):
            n = -(-max_b // max_a)
            # n = math.ceil(max_b / max_a), if you cannot assume ints.
            return [min_a, max_a], [n*min_a, n*max_a]

        elif (min_b < min_a) & (max_b < max_a):
            n = -(-max_a // max_b)
            # n = math.ceil(max_b / max_a), if you cannot assume ints.
            return [n*min_b, n*max_b], [min_b, max_b]

        elif (min_b < min_a) & (max_a < max_b):
            n = max( -(-max_b // max_a), -(min_b // min_a) )
            return [min_b / n, max_b / n], [min_b, max_b]

        elif (min_a < min_b) & (max_b < max_a):
            n = max( -(-max_a // max_b), -(min_a // min_b) )
            return [min_a, max_a], [min_a / n, max_a / n]
        elif (min_a == min_b):
            m = max(max_a, max_b)
            return [min_a, m], [min_b,  m]
        elif max_a == max_b:
            m = min(min_a, min_b)
            return [m, max_a], [m, max_b]

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

y0 = np.random.randint(-5, 35, 6)
y1 = np.random.randint(-7, 28, 6)

print(y0, y1)
range0, range1 = make_proportional_intervals(y0, y1)

traces = [
    go.Bar(
        x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
        y=y0, 
        name='y actual'
    ), 
    go.Bar(
        x=[1], 
        y=[0], 
        name='y dummy', 
        hoverinfo='none', 
        showlegend=False
    ), 
    go.Bar(
        x=[1],
        y=[0],
        yaxis='y2', 
        name='y2 dummy', 
        hoverinfo='none', 
        showlegend=False
    ),
   go.Bar(
       x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
       y=y1, 
       yaxis='y2', 
       name='y2 actual'
   )
]

# layout
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='group',
    yaxis=dict(
        title='y actual', 
        rangemode="tozero", 
        #anchor='x', 
        overlaying='y2',
        side="left",
        range = range0
    ),
    yaxis2=dict(
        title='y2 actual', 
        side='right', 
        rangemode = "tozero",
        #anchor='x',
        range = range1
    )
)

fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
iplot(fig)
```

Again, this is all just a work around for the fact that you have negative numbers and cannot use `rangemode = "tozero"` as scene [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101767/python-plotly-align-y-axis-for-scatter-and-bar). Perhaps the developers will add something in the future to `rangemode` to correct for this.

Comment: you are right. this is bit annoying but it works. thanks

Comment: If you have a general idea of how your data will be structured ahead of time you can write a function that will compute the ranges for you automatically. However, if you have no idea how your data will look the function can get complex and it may be easier to plot it once and then adjust the range manually.

Comment: yes but I'm automating this process for hundreds of such plots all of them in different ranges, due to which manual adjustment wouldn't be a feasible solution in my case

Comment: @ThReSholD See updates to try and solve the automation problem

Comment: Thanks for that function, exactly what I needed.